# Efficient way to check and insert data into MySQL database node

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, database, insert

First Way:

1. Fetch all the records from the database and create a result array.
2. Loop the new inserting array and check the unique id is exist or not with the above result array then inserting to the DB.

Second Way:

1. Loop the new inserting array and check the unique id is exist or not in the database then insert into the database.

Note: Inserting data will be very less compared to the database table data.

Please suggest any best way to do it.

Comment: Do you want to insert if the record does not yet exist or update in case it does exist?

Comment: If we knew your table structure and conditions it would help.  BUT if it's just duplicates - an INSERT... SELECT would probably be fastest as it is all done in the database.

Comment: Any reason to do not rely on DB unique costrains?

Comment: i reckon sub-query/nested-query could be solution here..

Comment: Only inserting the data. if the record exists no need to insert.

Answer (score 0):

An implemetation of @NigelRen idea

```
insert into destTable  (id, coln,...)
select st.id,st.coln,...
from srcTable st
left join destTable dt on st.id=dt.id
where dt.id is null
```

where `id`  is the relation **one-to-one** between the two tables

Comment: Inserting the data is not from the table it is from input array(API).